# How do i change the value in a cell using google script?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

im actually a beginner in google scripts, and I would like to seek some help regarding how do I change the password for an account in webapp and it would link to google sheet. So currently I'm doing a payment webapp and I'm using google sheet as my database, there's a list of username and password at google sheet. Would it that be possible for me to change the password in the webapp and it would overwrite the old ones inside google sheet?

The link to the source code:
https://script.google.com/d/1mR9Cy1ylLA4CdhbD69m8uZPFN9HzPJupl3R197GR9A-7cZNnnsCH18Is/edit?usp=sharing

The link to the google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bM8l6JefFsPrlJnTWf56wOhnuSjdIwg3hMbY1tN1Zp8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It is possible.  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('your sheet name').getRange('A1'). setValue();  It would overwrite the old  password if you program it to do so.  You can use google.script.run from the webapp.  All of this is explained in the documentation.

Comment: Shld i edit it in code.gs or inside the <script> of that particular HTML page?

Comment: I think that's something you have to figure out for yourself.  Or ask a specific question about a specific part of the code that you have posted into your question.

Answer (score 1):

SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('your sheet name').getRange('A1').setValue();